# Where's Whatsapp identity (private) key located?

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, signal-private-messenger

According to the end-end-end encrypted messaging protocol named Signal Protocol and implemented also in Whatsapp, each user has a long-term identity key pair, in addition to some one-time ephemeral keys and a signed prekey.

The identity key, namely the one mentioned in the official [documentation](https://scontent-fco2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.8562-6/309473131_1302549333851760_6207638168445881915_n.pdf?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=ad8a9d&_nc_ohc=5LgX9LwZXrQAX_jxK6A&_nc_ht=scontent-fco2-1.xx&oh=00_AT-ufvZCX0Iqf6hLRS6QjklA2JfDtUUaMa0szXYhD6eEBw&oe=63467C9D) in page 4, is used in the first triple Diffie-Hellman agreement and signs all the prekeys.

Does anybody know where this key pair is saved?

I'm assuming here a full access to the memory of the device.
In the axolotl.db file I can find traces of current ratcheting keys but not of the identity key.

Comment: Force stop the WhatsApp app, set [`inotifywatch`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywatch.1.html) on the app's data directories, open the app, send a message, check `inotify` event log to find out which files were accessed.

Comment: [Signal](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/240236) E2EE is bonded to [TEE](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) (can't speak for [Whatsapp](https://thehackernews.com/2022/08/facebook-testing-default-end-to-end.html) guess not)